# Simple SQL problem with join and group by

Tags: sql, group-by

This is the schema of my db

```
table emp
eid     ename   age salary
1000    Lakmal  33  90000
1001    Nadeeka 24  28000



 table works
    eid     did             percentage
    1000    Admin           40
    1000    ITSD            50
    1001    Admin           100
    1002    Academic        100
    1003    Academic        30
```

I want to Display the employees’ name and the total percentage he/she has worked in total.

And this is what I tried

```
  select sum(w.pct_time) as 'Total' ,e.ename 
from emp e, works w
where w.eid = e.eid group by w.eid
```

and this is not working, i get this error

```
Column 'emp.ename' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

can anyone explain how to obtain above output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the expected result with the given sample data in tabular form.

Comment: Using this old-style join is not suggested, but use ANSI-92 standard, instead. Btw, what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your `group by` clause as below.

```
select sum(w.pct_time) as 'Total' ,e.ename from emp e, works w where w.eid = e.eid group by e.ename
```

Note: Here, I am assuming that names are unique since you only need to display `ename` and `pct_time`. If not, this will not give correct results as it will combine the results of all employees with same name.

If names are not unique, you can add `e.eid` as well in `group by` clause.

```
select sum(w.pct_time) as 'Total' ,e.ename from emp e, works w where w.eid = e.eid group by e.eid, e.ename
```

Comment: yeah this is working but i want to know is this method reliable what if a had 2 employees  with same name but different ids? , ename is not the primary key of emp table

Comment: No. For that, you can add `e.eid` also in `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for percentage calculation

```
Select (Sum(pct_time)* 100 / (Select Sum(pct_time) From works)) as 'Total',
        e.ename, e.eid
  From emp e
  Join works w
    On e.eid = w.eid
 Group By e.ename, e.eid
```

using inner join is enough, if all people worked included in the `emp` table. You seem to have all employees, but some work records for some identification numbers are missing.

Comment: problem here is i cant select e.ename because im grouping by with w.eid and i cant group with e.ename beacuse its not unique

Comment: so simply i cant group with e.ename if i get  2 employees with same name
its not gonna work

Comment: @UshanFernando OK, add `e.eid` besides `e.ename` then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full working SQL Server sample, with tables converted to common table expressions:

```
with [emp] (eid, ename, age, salary)
as
(
    select
        eid,     ename,   age, salary
    from
    (
        values 
            (1000 ,  ' Lakmal', 33,  90000),
            (1001 ,   'Nadeeka', 24,  28000)
    )  as result (eid,     ename,   age, salary)
),
[works] (eid, did, pct_time)
as
(
    select
        eid, did, percentage
    from
    (    
        values 
            (1000,    'Admin', 40),
            (1000,    'ITSD', 50),
            (1001,    'Admin', 100),
            (1002,    'Academic', 100),
            (1003,    'Academic', 30)
    )  as result(eid, did, percentage)
),
[grouped] (eid, pct)
as
(
    ' Do the grouping here.
    select
         e.eid, sum(w.pct_time) 
    from
       emp e
    inner join  
       works w on w.eid = e.eid
    group by
        e.eid
)
' And now you can join the grouped results with the employees to display the names
select 
   [w].pct as 'Total', e.ename 
from 
   [emp] e
inner join  
   [grouped] w on w.eid = e.eid;
```